# combining GO GIN-GONIC GORM and VALIDATOR.V2

Tags: validation, go, go-gorm, go-gin

I am quite new to Go and I would like to startup by setting a GIN-GONIC API. I found this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@thedevsaddam/build-restful-api-service-in-golang-using-gin-gonic-framework-85b1a6e176f3#.tip4h672r) and I am very happy with that skeleton. But now I am stuck with the validating process which I added: "gopkg.in/validator.v2" and

```
type Todo struct {
    gorm.Model
    Title     string `json:"title"`
    Completed int `json:"completed"`
}
```

became

```
type Todo struct {
    gorm.Model
    Title     string `json:"title" **validate:"size:2"**`
    Completed int `json:"completed"`
}
```

and then in the `CreateTodo` function which I added :

```
if errs := validator.Validate(todo); errs!=nil {
    c.JSON(500, gin.H{"Error": errs.Error()})
}
```

but then a POST call send :

> "Error": "Type: unknown tag"

after some research I found that :

> Using a non-existing validation func in a field tag will always return false and with error `validate.ErrUnknownTag`.

so the `**validate:"size:2"**` must be wrong ...

I don't get how to set the validation and also how to display the correct error within the "catch":

```
c.JSON(500, gin.H{"Error": errs.Error()})
```

Comment: Thanks l159, I did read twice ... but it's not easy ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you haven't defined `size` validation function. Also you can do it.

#### [Custom validation functions](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/validator.v2#hdr-Custom_validation_functions):

```
func size(v interface{}, param int) error {
    st := reflect.ValueOf(v)
    if st.Kind() != reflect.String {
        return validate.ErrUnsupported
    }

    if utf8.RuneCountInString(st.String()) != param {
        return errors.New("Wrong size")
    }
    return nil
}

validate.SetValidationFunc("size", size)
```

Comment: Thanks, I missread and thought that size was a builtin function, I probably mixed with the gorm doc ....

Comment: I cannot find out where to put the validate.SetValidationFunc("size", size) when after the size function I got : syntax error: non-declaration statement outside function body but if I put it within main I got undefined: validate in validate.SetValidationFunc

Comment: Place it before `validator.Validate(todo)`

Comment: I did but not working : validate.SetValidationFunc("checkURL", checkURL)
 if errs := validator.Validate(todo); errs!=nil {                 I keep getting : undefined: validate in validate.SetValidationFunc   and I did add import for "gopkg.in/validator.v2" and "reflect" ....

Comment: It is language basics and doesn't related to the question.

Comment: yes, I probably missunderstood something else, you are right, I will go back in my books, thanks anyway !